# Drop Extended Event Session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, database-administration, extended-events

When I drop xevent , it' s deleted successfully but log file not deleted . how can I delete it with log file
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server)

```
   DROP EVENT SESSION mySession ON SERVER;
```

Comment: It seems you can't.you have to manually delete them

Comment: I thing Microsoft has done the business wrong